# CSS scroll/translateY an element if it overflows

Tags: html, css, animation

Is it possible to optionally "scroll" an element if it grows beyond its bounding-box size? That is, say I have a div with `overflow: hidden` and a list of items within, I'd like to have a looping animation which, over the course of the animation, displays all the items in the list, "scrolling" (translateY?) to the bottom and then back to the top. Here's my best attempt at an ascii art example:

```
                             AAAAAA                             
               AAAAAA        BBBBBB        AAAAAA               
+------+      +------+      +------+      +------+      +------+
|AAAAAA|      |BBBBBB|      |CCCCCC|      |BBBBBB|      |AAAAAA|
+------+  ->  +------+  ->  +------+  ->  +------+  ->  +------+
 BBBBBB        CCCCCC                      CCCCCC        BBBBBB 
 CCCCCC                                                  CCCCCC
```

I don't know a lot about css, but I've been reading up on it and css animations. I'm wondering if there's a way to "conditionally" trigger such an animation? Or, would it be possible to write the animation in such a way that it could always be running and would just do the right thing even if the whole list was visible (that is, it was short enough that it was not overflowing), and then as the list grew, the effect of the animation would actually show up?

*EDIT*: I should clarify I'd like to achieve a "scrolling"-style of animation, rather than just instantaneously replacing the elements that are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pure CSS animation that I think does what you're looking for.  Basically it uses Keyframes to scroll the `#inner` div using translateY inside the `#outer` div.  At 50% we stop at 100% of the height of `#inner` (-101px so we don't scroll past the last item and it's margin), then at 100% you're back to the start.  You can change the speed in which it animates in the `#inner` declaration.

By using `calc` and percents, this solution accommodates any number of slides without having to alter the CSS.  Also by adding infinite to the animation declaration you can run the slide back and forth infinitely.

```css
#outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  }
  
#inner {
  height: auto;
  -webkit-animation: scrolly 10s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: scrolly 10s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: scrolly 10s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: scrolly 10s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}

#inner img {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 1px 0;
}


@-webkit-keyframes scrolly {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0px); }
  50%  { transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 101px)); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes scrolly {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0px); }
  50%  { transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 101px)); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0px); }
}
@-o-keyframes scrolly {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0px); }
  50%  { transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 101px)); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0px); }
}
@keyframes scrolly {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0px); }
  50%  { transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 101px)); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0px); }
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner'>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=A"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=B"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=C"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=D"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That pretty much nails it! I didn't know about the `calc()` function, that will come in very handy. Great work!

Comment: Yep. `calc()` is great.  Just make sure your target browser audience supports it. https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am not sure exactly how you are wanting the animation to look, but here is a vanilla JS/CSS slideshow animation. If you want it to slideUp/down you can simply modify the CSS animation so rather than changing display, it will change it's position by adding/subtracting a margin to the element.

```js
//Changed index so 1 is actually first image, rather than starting at 0 index
var index = 1;
var paused = false;
var slideShow = [];

for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow").length; i++) {
  slideShow[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow")[i];
  slideShow[i].style.display = "none";
}

slideShow[0].style.display = "inline";

var slides = setInterval(function() {
  if (index < slideShow.length) {
    index++;
    showDivs();
  }
  else {
    index = 1;
    showDivs();
 }
},1000);

function control(n) {
  clearInterval(slides);

  if (index+n > slideShow.length) {
    index = 1;
  }
  else if (index+n <= 0) {
    index = slideShow.length;
  }
  else {
    index += n;
  }
  showDivs();
}

function showDivs() {
  //Hide all slideShow elements, and then show only the targeted element
  for (let i=1; i<=slideShow.length; i++) {
    slideShow[i-1].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideShow[index-1].style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<button  onclick="control(-1)" class="arrows" id="left"><</button>
<p class="slideShow">1</p>
<p class="slideShow">2</p>
<p class="slideShow">3</p>
<p class="slideShow">4</p>
<p class="slideShow">5</p>
<button onclick="control(1)" class="arrows" id="right">></button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's in interesting approach. I might not have made it clear in my original question but I'm hoping to accomplish a smoot, continuous scroll from top to bottom (and then back from bottom to top). This appears to be much more like just replacing the visible content all at once.

Comment: Yeah, the CSS animation needs modifying. I'll edit once I get time but try making the animation change margin rather than display.